# Find and replace using regex with sed

Tags: sed, json

I'm trying to find and replace in a file:

```
echo "$BRANCH_NAME" >> "$WORKING_DIR"/test.text
    sed -i '' "remote_paths/.*[\/]([^\"]*)/$BRANCH_NAME/g" "$WORKING_DIR"/sftp-config.json
```

... the script successfully creates `test.text` and prints the `BRANCH_NAME` so I know its working good so far. However I can't get the find and replace working.

The regex output is, in case you're wondering:

```
Full match  `remote_path": "/home/myname/public_html/ABC-1271`
Group 1.    `ABC-1271`
```

In simple terms, this is what I'm trying to achieve:

Find `ABC-1271` in **string** `remote_path": "/home/myname/public_html/ABC-1271` of **file** `sftp-config.json` and replace `ABC-1271` with `XYZ-1225` (`$BRANCH_NAME`)

Comment: (1) What is in the `sftp-config.json` input file?  (2) What is the value of `$BRANCH_NAME`?  (3) Please describe in sentences (English sentences constructed of English words) what you want this `sed` command to do.  (4) What do you mean by “The regex output”? Do you mean the output from `sed`?  (5) It’s good practice to debug your `sed` commands *without* the `-i` option, and then add it when the text manipulation functionality is working.  (6) Why are you searching for `remote_paths` when your file contains `remote_path`?

Comment: @G-Man (1) It contains the sFTP info including the remote_path, this script is a git hook that changed the path on switching the branch (2) its the working directory name, for example XYZ-1225 (3) find ABC-1271 in `remote_path": "/home/myname/public_html/ABC-1271` in the file sftp-config.json and replace ABC-1271 with XYZ-1225 (4) No the result if I run regex on sftp-config.json (5) Ah ok (6) To find and replace

Comment: See also [How to ensure that string interpolated into \`sed\` substitution escapes all metachars](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/129059)

Answer (score 2):

Your `sed` command is a bit messed up.

```
sed -i '' "remote_paths/.*[\/]([^\"]*)/$BRANCH_NAME/g"
```

First of all, don't use `sed` with `-i` if you're still trying to get thing to work. That's just a recipe for destroying important files.

Secondly, the `r` in `remote_path` is a `sed` command that reads a file. I'm pretty sure it looks for a file called `emote_paths/.*[\/]([^\"]*)/$BRANCH_NAME/g` or at least `emote_paths`.  In either case, it won't exit with an error if the file does not exist.

It looks like you'd wanted something like

```
s#\(remote_path.*/home/myname/public_html/\)\([A-Z0-9-]*\)#\1$BRANCH_NAME#g
```

The command becomes

```
sed "s#\(remote_path.*/home/myname/public_html/\)\([A-Z0-9-]*\)#\1$BRANCH_NAME#g" \
  "$WORKING_DIR/sftp-config.json" >"$WORKING_DIR/sftp-config.json.new"
```

Or, if the branch name is the last thing on the line after the last `/` and the string `remote_path` uniquely locates this line:

```
sed "/remote_path/s#/[^/]*\$#$BRANCH_NAME#" \
  "$WORKING_DIR/sftp-config.json" >"$WORKING_DIR/sftp-config.json.new"
```

Ideally, though, you'd be using a JSON-aware tool for doing this, for example [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/):

```
jq ".remote_path = (.remote_path | split(\"/\") | .[-1] = \"$BRANCH_NAME\" | join(\"/\"))" \
  input.json >output.json
```

Comment: @3zzy if that's a clarification to your question please edit your question and put it there where it's easy for everyone to find. Updates in comments can easily get overlooked.

Comment: Yes, just updated the description

Comment: @Philippos The `''` is an argument to the `-i` flag.  It's modifying the file in-place.

Comment: Oh, thank you! Seems I'm too much used to gnu `sed` with no arguments for `-i`. Sorry.

Comment: @Kusalananda This is what the sftp-config looks like: https://pastebin.com/SqTzd2sQ

Comment: @3zzy Hmm... That JSON is broken. It has `//` comments (JSON doesn't support comments as far as I know), and it has a trailing comma after the last value.

Comment: @3zzy If the file is valid JSON, you may use the command at the end of my answer to do the modification.

Answer (score 0):

(1) `remote_path` seems to be an address, filtering the line with that pattern? Then surround it by slashes: `/remote_path/`

(2) You seem to create an expression for the whole line, but only want to replace the part you marked with `()`. Right? But they are used very differently (grouping or back references) and you'd need to escape them `\(\)`or use option `-E` for extended regular expressions

(3) Find a pattern that matches only the branch name to be replaced like a dash between uppercase letters and numbers: `[A-Z]*-[0-9]*`

We end up with

```
sed -i '' "/remote_path/s/[A-Z]*-[0-9]*)/$BRANCH_NAME/g" "$WORKING_DIR"/sftp-config.json
```

And try it without the `-i` option first